# Inheritance implementation not working

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an interface called Generator that looks like this:

```
class Generator{
public:
    virtual float getSample(Note &note)=0;
};
```

And my `Synth` class is implementing it, like this:

```
class Synth : public Generator{
public:
    virtual float getSample(Note &note);
};

float Synth::getSample(Note &note){
    return 0.5;
}
```

I'm trying to call the getSample method from my Note class (which has a generator member)

```
class Note : public Playable{
public:
    Generator *generator;
    virtual float getValue();
};

float Note::getValue(){
    float sample = generator->getSample(*this); // gets stuck here
    return sample;
}
```

When I try to run, it gets stuck on the marked line in the code above. The problem is that I'm not getting a very clear error message. This is what I can see once it stops:

[image]
[image]

Comment: are you sure the generator member is initialized (the 'EXC_DAB_ACCES' seems to indicate otherwise)? Also you should probably use a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you never initialized the member `Note::generator`, so calling a function on it is undefined behavior.

Try, as a test:

```
float Note::getValue(){
    generator = new Synth;
    float sample = generator->getSample(*this); // gets stuck here
    return sample;
}
```

If it works, go back and review your logic. Use a `std::unique_ptr<Generator>` instead of a raw pointer. Create a constructor for `Node`. Initialize the pointer there.

Comment: It worked with `generator = new Synth;`, I wasn't initializing `generator` correctly, like you said. It was pointing to another empty pointer actually. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Sled okay, then you know what you have to do :)

Comment: Yep, I'll have a look at unique_ptr too, didn't know about that.